# SQL - Query Problems using join

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are my queries, query 1 works fine.
[image]

But query 2 gives null, the only difference is that i am trying to compare the time on line 4. The begin time is 14:00:00 and end is 14:10:00, so it should give me a value.

In the tutorial table there can be many tutorials with the same room number and time, there is no date i handle that in the marks table.

Could i be using the wrong join type? or do i need to use union.

Comment: Your condition is not going to match that begin time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead

```
and '14:05:00' >= tutorial.begin
and '14:05:00' <= tutorial.finish
```

Your existing `where` only matches when `tutorial.begin` and `tutorial.finish` both `= '14:05:00'`.

Answer (score 1):

Begin time of 14:00 and end at 14:10 does not meet the criteria.

Try the following: 
`tutorial.begin >= '14:00:00' AND tutorial.finish <= '14:10:00'`

Edit: Changed answer after reading over question again